# Best practice for UI testing an app in kiosk mode

Tags: uiautomation, desktop-application, best-practices, winappdriver

I have a Windows 10 UWP app that runs in kiosk mode in production, and I'm wondering what the best practice would be if I want to create automated UI tests for it. Like, how necessary would it be to run the app itself in kiosk mode in order to do UI tests? It seems like I'd want to, as running it in kiosk mode would be much more realistic than just firing it up as a .exe and having it run as a normal desktop app-but I don't know if that's even really possible to do that in kiosk mode.

Answer (score 0):

> Auto launches a UWP app in full screen and prevents access to other system functions, while monitoring the lifecycle of the kiosk app. Only supports one single-app kiosk profile under one account per device. - [Source](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/iot-enterprise/kiosk-mode/kiosk-mode)

So if you want to check the UI, launching it in the same resolution on your desktop is more-or-less the same thing. You might need to set Portrait Mode in AppManifest's Application tab.